# is a jar file read more than once while the JVM executes an application?

Tags: java, jvm

Does the JVM read a `.jar` file from disk more than once for a long running program or is it read only once and the whole image is in memory until the JVM terminates?

I was running a job that took about 26 hours and near the end there was an undefined object exception (`NoClassDefFoundError`) that I think might be due to the fact that I was making code changes and re-exported the `.jar` from the development environment (that is, I created a new one on the disk at the same place the old one was) while the application was running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to run your code with the flag `-verbose:class` and you will see that class loading is extremely lazy. The JVM loads just the classes it absolutely must have to go on. If, on the end of your program, you're doing something that requires a class that was not absolutly needed before, it'll get loaded just then.

This explains very well the error you got, and you should notice that you shouldn't replace a jar (or class) file that is running, exactly for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

No, JVM reads from jar every time when it needs to load a new class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using import and normal use of classes, than only once per class.

If you play with class loaders, reflections than you can make extra reads and "not planed behavior" - it means many times per class.

Comment: For the usual import case, is it read once per class import or once for total?

Comment: The program does a little reflection but not involving the object that was threw an exception due to being missing.

Comment: as it Evgeniy Dorofeev says, it reads every time, when it loads a ( new ) class. Once read the class, than it will not read again that one, unless you unload, change references, use JNI to hack it.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with *import statements*. You could have 1000 of unused import statements, and it won't load one single class at runtime, unless needed for different reasons.